# android keypad force set orientation

Tags: android, keyboard, orientation

My App is `portrait` only. In `AndroidManifest.xml`, I declared `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`.

But I want to show landscape Keypad in specific Scene.
My layout is arrange portrait. so I don't use below api.

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

I wanna landscape keypad in my portrait only app.
is there any way?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);` I never tried this but this may help you to achieve your goal.